# How can I screen share and camera video same time in different tracks?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, agora.io, videochat, screensharing

I am testing Agora features for a web app that already uses webRTC. Currently, it works with one separate track for audio and two video tracks: one for the camera and another for the screen share.

When I tried to share the screen I couldn`t publish it without unpublish the camera track, like the doc for 4.x sdk version says: https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/develop/product-workflow?platform=web

[Agora.io screen share sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM7FD.png)

How can I solve this? For me appears to be a typical case on a video chat, where one user shares his screen and keeps showing his audio and video to present something.

My code:

```
  async startScreenShare(id?: string): Promise<void> {
    let stream: MediaStream;
    if (!id) {
      stream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getDisplayMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: true,
      });
    } else {
      const constraint = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
            chromeMediaSourceId: id,
          },
        },
      };

      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint as any);
    }

    const videoTrack = stream.getTracks()[0];

    this.rtc.screenVideoTrack = AgoraRTC.createCustomVideoTrack({
      mediaStreamTrack: videoTrack,
    });

    this.rtc.client.unpublish(this.rtc.localVideoTrack);

    await this.rtc.client.publish(this.rtc.screenVideoTrack);

  }
```

It is working but losing the camera track.

Answer (score 0):

An `AgoraRTCClient` object can publish **only one video track**.

Create new `AgoraRTCClient` to publish another track.

See "Enable both screen sharing and video" section of [Agora Docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/3.x/video-calling/basic-features/screensharing?platform=web#enable-both-screen-sharing-and-video).

Comment: Thanks. Does it work only on the old version? Because that page doesn't exist in the 4.x version only on 3.x.

Comment: It is still working in 4.x.
The concept(one client - one video) will not change, i think.

Comment: Does it mean that to publish the video screen and screen share, I need to use AgoraRTCClient in two separate components?